# Save event is not getting triggered on updateMany function

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

For some reason, pre nor post event is getting triggered when data is updated thru updateMany function in Mongoose 5.2.7.

Init event is getting triggered though.

Following is the code

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name           : { type: String },
  address        : { type: String },
}, { versionKey: false });

schema.set('collection', 'test');

schema.pre('save', function() {
  console.log('--- PRE SAVE ----');
})

schema.post('save', function() {
  console.log('--- POST SAVE ----');
})
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here `pre('save', () => {})` is getting triggered with `save` call only and `updateMany` and `save` are not the same. You need to call `save()` to trigger `pre and post save` events here.

Comment: Thank you. Resolved by adding schema.pre('updateMany') method.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding schema.pre('updateMany') method.